# One page checkout without login/registration

Tags: opencart, checkout

How do I make the buying process very simple without registration:

[image]

What I need is here?

```
catalog/controller/checkout
catalog/language/english/checkout
catalog/model/checkout
catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout
```

Or somewhere else?

Comment: Have you looked in the [Opencart Extension directory](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension&filter_search=checkout)? There are a lot of extensions which will simplify the checkout process.

Comment: I would like to do it myself to get practice and understand the code OpenCart.

Comment: I think customizing the Opencart checkout process with limited knowledge about it can be difficult. What you can do best is looking at other (free?) extensions, how do they work and how do they change the checkout process. Based on that information you can start to customize your own checkout. If you then run into problems you can ask more specific questions about it.

Comment: I guess you're right, I'll try to change themselves under this module: [link](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=17278&filter_search=checkout%20simple%20one%20page&page=2)

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified the registration form:
http://i62.tinypic.com/veufqp.jpg

A problem with catalog\model\account\customer.php
http://i59.tinypic.com/11ujfq0.jpg

I understand what went wrong, the model does not receive the necessary variables.
But how to drown out the missing variables?
The right to request in the model or you can somehow do it in the controller?

Location data model takes ?:
- POST
- date
- session